.NET MAUI How To Perform Nested Bindings?
I want to use bindings of multiple CollectionView within a CarouselView. However, how can one perform that?
Visually, I'm trying something like the following:
<--CarouselView: Questions------------------------>
|                                                 |
|  <Label: QuestionContent />                     |
|                                                 |
|  <--CollectionView: Images---------------->     |
|  |                                        |     |
|  <---------------------------------------->     |
|                                                 |
|  <--CollectionView: Answers--------------->     |
|  |                                        |     |
|  <---------------------------------------->     |
|                                                 |
<------------------------------------------------->

I've tried to perform the following:
The Model classes are the following:
public class Question : ObservableObject
{
    public int QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string QuestionContent { get; set; }
}

public class Image : ObservableObject
{
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
}

public partial class Answer : ObservableObject
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int? QuestionType { get; set; }
}

The ViewModel would be like the following:
public partial class ViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Question> _questions = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Image> _images = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Answer> _answers = new();
}

And the View looks like the following:
<!-- Questions Carousel View -->
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame BorderColor="{StaticResource NightBlue}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- QuestionContent -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="{Binding QuestionContent}"/>

                    <!-- Images -->
                    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="{x:Binding}"
                                           MaximumWidthRequest="200"
                                           MaximumHeightRequest="200" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>

                    <!-- Answers -->
                    <CollectionView Grid.Row="2"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Answers">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <!-- Answer Text -->
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                           Text="{x:Binding Content}"
                                           TextColor="{StaticResource NightBlue}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>

However, this seems not to work. At least, Binding Diagnostics gives warnings of not being able to find the binding properties. How can I resolve this?
UPDATE:
I have, as suggested, combined the model classes to a nested representation, as following:
public partial class QuestionBlock : ObservableObject
{
    public Question question { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Image>? images { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Answer> answers { get; set; }
    public bool? isChecked { get; set; }
}

Now, I have a problem on top of that I don't know how to resolve:
I want to portray a RadioButton or a CheckBox next to the corresponding answer, similar to the following:
<--CarouselView: Questions--------------------------->
|                                                    |
|  <Label: QuestionContent />                        |
|                                                    |
|  <--CollectionView: Images---------------->        |
|  |                                        |        |
|  <---------------------------------------->        |
|                                                    |
|  <--CollectionView: Answers--------------------->  |
|  |  <Button/CheckBox> <Label: Answer.Content /> |  |
|  <---------------------------------------------->  |
|                                                    |
<---------------------------------------------------->

However, the Button/CheckBox is depended on Question.QuestionType, whereas the label portrays Answer.Content. The View is has the following:
<!-- Answers -->
<CollectionView
                x:DataType="models:QuestionBlock"
                ItemsSource="{Binding answers}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout
                           Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <Grid Padding="20">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- Radio Button for Standard Questions -->
                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0"
                                 x:DataType="models:QuestionBlock"
                                 GroupName="radioButtonGroup"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 IsVisible="{Binding question.QuestionType, Converter={StaticResource QuestionTypeIsStandardToBooleanConverter}}" />

                    <!-- Check Box for Multiple Choice Questions -->
                    <CheckBox 
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        x:DataType="models:QuestionBlock"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding question.QuestionType, Converter={StaticResource QuestionTypeIsMultipleChoiceToBooleanConverter}}"
                        />

                    <!-- Answer Text -->
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           x:DataType="models:Answer"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Text="{Binding Content}"
                           TextColor="{StaticResource NightBlue}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

How can I resolve this issue? The IsVisible seems to have binding problems, probably with the multiple DataTypes? Do you know, how to resolve this?

Your three VM properties are all dependent of each other, not nested.  You need to structure the data so that it is actually nested

What exactly do you mean by that? Building a new class like "QuestionBlock" that has a Question, ObservableCollection and ObservableCollection property?

Have you tried setting the datatype for each data template:
x:DataType="Answer"

Yea, exactly.  A nested UI requires nested data

@Jason But how do I reference in a nested way? Assuming the QuestionBlock model from above, how do I reference Question.QuestionContent, for example? Can I use in a label just "Text={Binding Question.QuestionContent}"? Do I need to set a DataType?

Yes, just use dot notation like you would in a C# statement

That's the issue with Bindings. Here are two ways to solve it.
Option1, use Relative Bindings.
The CheckBox and the RadioButton both are in the CollectionView's DataTemplate. The default BindingContext is each answer in answers collection. So, we should use Relative Bindings to find the QuestionBlock which is the ancestor's BindingContext. You may see the docs here, Bind to an ancestor. Please try the following code for IsVisible Property
IsVisible="{Binding question.QuestionType,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:QuestionBlock}}}"

By the way, set x:DataType cannot set the BindingContext.
Option2, use x:Reference,
We set the name of Frame to "myframe". Because this Frame's BindingContext is QuestionBlock,
<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Frame x:Name="myframe">
            <Grid>
 ...

And we access the BindingContext of Frame use x:Reference,
 IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.question.QuestionType,Source={x:Reference myframe}}" />

Hope it helps!
